Defaulting three way comparison operator in recursive data structures
I'd like to use a defaulted three-way comparison operator in a recursive data structure, like this:
struct MyStruct {
  int i;
  std::vector<MyStruct> v;
  std::partial_ordering operator<=>(const MyStruct &a) const = default;
};

// Fails: can't infer comparison result type
static_assert(std::same_as<std::compare_three_way_result_t<MyStruct>,
          std::partial_ordering>);

Unfortunately, there seems to be a circular dependency, because the defaulted <=> operator depends on the comparison categories of integer comparison and std::vector, while the vector comparison category depends on the comparison category if its value_type, namely MyStruct.  The fact that I've explicitly declared the comparison type to be std::partial_ordering doesn't seem to help, even though it should.  In particular, it does work if I implement the function by hand:
struct MyStruct {
  int i;
  std::vector<MyStruct> v;
  std::partial_ordering operator<=>(const MyStruct &other) const {
    if (auto r = i <=> other.i; r != 0)
      return r;
    return v <=> other.v;
  }
};

// OK
static_assert(std::same_as<std::compare_three_way_result_t<MyStruct>,
          std::partial_ordering>);

My questions:

Is there any way to short-circuit this problem?  The spec prohibits overloading std::compare_three_way_result, but is there some other way to affect vector or std::lexicographical_compare_three_way?

Is there any way, using concepts or requires clauses, to detect an incomplete type?  As an alternative, I could design my own vector-like container class that just defaults to std::partial_ordering when the type is incomplete.



Three way operator is auto x = false ? 1 : 2. What you refer is (informally) called the spaceship operator

@PepijnKramer I've never heard the conditional operator being called the "three way operator" (ternary yes, but that's three parts, not three way), the official name of the "spaceship operator" is the three way comparison operator

@AlanBirtles Oops, I really should not answer before my first coffee in the morning. Me bad ;)

If you indeed specify std::partial_ordering yourself (i.e. without auto), then you can define the comparison operator outside the class as an inline function. At that point, the class is complete.
struct MyStruct {
  int i;
  std::vector<MyStruct> v;
  std::partial_ordering operator<=>(const MyStruct &) const;
};

inline std::partial_ordering MyStruct::operator<=>(const MyStruct &) const = default;

I'm not sure your original code really is ill-formed either come to think of it (meaning = default; in the member specification is a complete class context already), unless there's a standard defect I missed.

Well, g++ accepts your suggestion, but clang++ 18.1 rejects it with both libc++ and libstdc++.

@user3188445 - I tinkered with it, and I strongly suspect it's a clang frontend bug, centered around defaulting comparison ops (there's a fair few of those reported https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+defaulted+operator). For instance, I simplified the example a bit to default operator== instead, and I got this compiler crash in Clang 17 (which also rejected my proposal upon review). I think your explicit definition is the best workaround left.
